# Method not found in JSF view

Tags: java, jsf, methods, xhtml

How would I implement a login page using JSF? At the moment I have a registration form which stores the values in a variable in a Java Bean.
I now need to create a log in and log out page for this. How would I go about on achieving this ?

Here is **the code for the bean** :

```
public String checkValidUser(String name) {
    dbData(name);
    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(dbUsername)) {
        if(password.equals(dbPassword)) {
            return "success.xhtml";
        }
        else {
            return "fail.xhtml";
        }
    }
    else {
        return "fail.xhtml";
    }
}
```

This is the **LogIn Page** :

```
            <h:outputText value="Forename"/>
            <h:inputText  id="forename" size="25" maxlength="30" required="true" 
                          requiredMessage="Please Enter Your Forename" 
                          validatorMessage="FR ERR" 
                          value="#{databaseLoginReg.name}">
                <f:validateLength maximum="30" minimum="1"/>
            </h:inputText>
            <h:message errorClass="error" for="forename"/>


            <h:outputText  value="Enter Password"/>
            <h:inputSecret id="password" size="25" maxlength="16" required="true"
                           requiredMessage="Please Enter a Password"
                           validatorMessage="ERR"
                           value="#{databaseLoginReg.password}">
                <f:validateLength maximum="16" minimum="8"/>
            </h:inputSecret>
            <h:message errorClass="error" for="password" />


            <h:commandButton value="Log In" action="{databaseLoginReg.checkValidUser}"/>
```

The error:

```
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /logIn.xhtml @47,94 action="#{databaseLoginReg.checkValidUser}": Method not found: databaseLoginReg@77ff927f.checkValidUser()
```

Comment: search google with "JAAS jsf"

Comment: Ok with some thinking and SQL i think ive sorted it but im having a problem with the navigation of success or failure. 

Wheh the Username and Password are matching it goes to success.xhtml and if if fails it goes to fail.xhtml. 

But the navigation doesnt work i get this error:

javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /login.xhtml @47,94 action="#{databaseLogin.checkUser}":Method Not Found: databaseLogin@7488c2a7.checkUser()

Comment: There's problem either with the managed-bean or the method. Show us the relevant code.

Comment: which code would you like to see?

Comment: This is the Method for checking which works, BUT navigation to pages dont:

  public String checkValidUser(String name)
    {
        dbData(name);
        
        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(dbUsername))
        {
            if(password.equals(dbPassword))
            {
                return "success.xhtml";
            }
            else 
            {
                return "fail.xhtml";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "fail.xhtml";
        }
    }

Comment: '                <h:commandButton value="Log In" action="#{databaseLoginReg.checkValidUser}"/> '

This is the button

Comment: Update the question with the necessary code of the view and managed-bean.

Comment: The line 47 holding `action="#{databaseLogin.checkUser}"` does not appear in the view. Does it exist in the managed-bean by the way ?

Comment: Ok on the  logIn.xhtml page i have:

<h:commandButton value="Log In" action="#{databaseLoginReg.checkValidUser}" which calls the chechValid user method

Comment: On the Bean i then have the method in the question above checkUserValid

Comment: But, does this method `checkUser()` exist in the managed-bean `DatabaseLogin` ?

Comment: Sorry i miss somewords when i typed the error here is the error:

javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /logIn.xhtml @47,94 action="#{databaseLoginReg.checkValidUser}": Method not found: databaseLoginReg@77ff927f.checkValidUser()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method's signature in the managed-Bean (with 1 String parameter) is different of the used in the view (without any parameters). That's why the JSF triggered the exception.
You should unify the method's signatures to enable its use through the view, for example, remove the parameter of the method `public String checkValidUser(){ ... }` while you can get the `name` and `password` easily in the managed-bean.

Comment: how do i do the navigation to the releveant pages if it fails or succeeds

Comment: It remains the same. What you should change is just _removing the pramaeter's method_ and **not** changing the return type of the method, it must keep `String`.

Comment: Welcome. Tip: When enunciating errors' StackTrace, just paste it as it is, to avoid such anomaly :)